# Tile windows horizontally in Windows 10 with the same behaviour as tile vertically

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to tile my windows horizontally in Windows 10 with the same behaviour as the vertical tile achieved by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>. The behaviour being: the windows snap to eachother and take up all space on my screen. The only way I've found to achieve something similar is to open a group of windows, right click task and select `Show windows stacked` but they don't snap and don't take up the whole screen.

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> maximizes and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> minimizes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Tile my windows horizontally with the same behavior as tiling them vertically. Open any window and press the Windows key + left or right arrow. If you're running Windows 10 it'll ask you which window to snap to the other side. If you're running Windows 7 it'll only snap one window. If you're running Windows 8, I'm sorry for your loss.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Windows10? [Cnet](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-windows-10s-new-snap-assist/) and [How-to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/198230/how-to-use-snap-assist-and-2x2-snap-on-windows-10/) both mention it but as I don't have the latest version of Windows 10, I cannot verify their claims.

Comment: I have the March 8th, 2016 build. It's not the latest. I took a look at the pages you suggested. the How-To-Geek page said it was possible to use Snap Assist vertically but it doesn't work for me. It just maximizes the window.

Comment: I have 10586.164

Comment: Then its probably part of the Windows 10 anniversary update.

Comment: On Windows 10, if you want to tile horizontally, say a number of command prompt windows, SHIFT+RIGHT click on the window group on the taskbar and select "Show all windows stacked".

Answer (score 27):

I have a workaround for that which still requires manual adjusting: do the regular "snap to" procedure with the WIN key + arrow left or right and then, still holding the WIN key, press the *UP* arrow so the window becomes a *quarter* of the screen rather than only the left or right half.  Release all keys, it will then ask you which window to resize to the other half; use the WIN key plus right, left, up or down keys in the same way, to arrange the other resulting quarter screen underneath the other window.  And then, finally, manually pull the right margins of both windows which should by now be horizontally tiled, to the end of the screen.

Comment: Nice answer. It is a pity Windows 10 does not provide two new shortcuts to avoid the manual part.

Answer (score 8):

The **PowerToys tool is an Windows 10** App that allows to create tiling-like windows layouts.
You can create layouts of multiple tiling-like windows and enable the tool to launch at start up so that it's always on display.
The video demonstrates it all.
There are other features. Which you can decide to enable or not.

So it's kind of a valid workaround. It involves no keyboard shorcuts, and no coding on your own.
You need to dimension the layout's windows yourself and then sav the layout. No redimensioning 'on the fly', but you can create many layouts to suit your needs.

- [1st PowerToys Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JY0caqFn2Uw)
- [2nd Youtube Demo + other tools in video description](https://youtu.be/4pteCeFXnsw?t=66)
- [PowerToys GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)
- [Power Toys Stable release .exe download page](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/)

Linux i3 Manager is also an App alternative for linux. But I haven't tested it.

- [Linux i3 Window Manager](https://i3wm.org/)

Comment: I don't see why people downvote this. FancyZones from PowerToys seems like a reasonable way to tile windows without manual alignment.

Comment: Yeah, I went this route. It's a pretty cool app if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by simple Powershell line:

```
(New-Object -ComObject  Shell.Application).TileHorizontally()
```

then you can create shortcut to .bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\script.ps1 >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

which silently opens .ps1 script and associate key shortcut to it.

Comment: seems to work fine - not sure what the downvote is for

Answer (score 0):

To tile windows horizontally in Win 11:

Open the first window and hold down `Microsoft Key` + `Left Alt Key` and press `Up Arrow Key`.
This will position that window into first half of the screen and will ask you to select the other window that you want to put in the second half of the screen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).